# Intellij: Change ctrl+space pop-up background

Tags: java, intellij-idea, popup, space, ctrl

I updated my Intellij Idea, and when the ctrl+space suggestion bar came up it went to a very disgusting colour, I want to change it back to blue. Can anybody help where can I change the colour?

Comment: I just want to change the ctrl+space pop up background color from grey to blue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change it by setting background for "Documentation" in "Settings (Preferences) | Editor | Color Scheme | General - Popups and Hints" and restarting IDE.

Comment: Thank you my friend you are my hero!!! Yes and you must restart the intellij because it wont work.

Comment: In 2019.3 version restart won't be needed

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to update my Intelllij idea, but assuming you simply want to change the appearance, go to Settings (Control+alt+s) -> Appearance and Behavior -> Appearance and you can control some color options. I would highly recommend installing a theme pack such as [Material](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui), it can really liven up the IDE and make it far better looking.